# Data taked from localStorage after rediraction with $router.push is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, local-storage, vue-router

In my Login component I make a request to get a JWT token, set it into localStorage and go to Home page.

```
const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
    login: this.login,
    password: this.password
});

localStorage.setItem('token', response.data);
this.$router.push('/');
```

In axios.js I set header with this token:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
```

In Home page (where i was redirected) in mounted hook I try to make request with this token, but i get error 401, because header Authorization = Bearer null. But if I refrash the page all is work. So why is it null after redirection?

```
async mounted() {
    const response = await axios.get('cinema/items');
    this.cinemas = response.data;
  }
```

Comment: when you set default headers, it is null, it is not refreshed for each time a request is made,. After login, you need to set default header again with new value.

Answer (score 0):

Axios [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) are functions run for every request/response.

In your case:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
    return config;
  },
  error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)
```

The difference between setting the headers at axios init rather than on every request is that the init happens before you get the token.

The reason why it works when you refresh the page is because you re-init axios, and this time the token is found in `localStorage`.
Note you shouldn't get and write a new token every time you start the app. You might want to only get a new one when there isn't one in `localStorage` or the existing one has expired.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried to do this, but for some reason it did not work. I solved my problem by using "config.headers.Authorization" instead of "config.headers.common['Authorization']"